# using absolute and flex in Firefox has position problem

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, absolute

My html tag like this, I have problem in Firefox when I use absolute and flex.
I need `<h2>` in the `someBox` bottom, but it float out `someBox` in Firefox.

```
<div class="leftPointBox">
  <a class="someBox">
    <div class="wrap">
      <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 414px)" srcset="img/420x315.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 413px)" srcset="img/800x600.jpg">
        <img src="img/800x600.jpg" srcset="img/420x315.jpg 414w, img/800x600.jpg 1024w">
      </picture>
    </div>
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

css(scss)：

```
.someBox {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
.leftPointBox{
    width: 380px;
    float: left;

    h2 {
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: #004E98;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 360px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
.someBox .wrap {
    height: 285px;
}

.wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){ flex: inherit; max-width: 100%;}
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Floats and flexbox don't like each other very much under certain conditions. I removed all floats to keep the document flow intact and "moved" the flexbox from `.wrap` to `.someBox`. Now, using [align-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) you can position the header at the bottom.

I set the height of `.someBox` at 600px just to demonstrate the header will be at the bottom.

```css
.someBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 600px; /* Demo purpose only */
}

.leftPointBox {
  width: 380px;
}

.leftPointBox h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #004E98;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}

.someBox .wrap {
  height: 285px;
}

.wrap {
}

.wrap img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftPointBox">
  <a class="someBox">
    <div class="wrap">
      <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 414px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/420x315">
        <source media="(min-width: 413px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/420x315 414w, https://via.placeholder.com/800x600 1024w">
      </picture>
    </div>
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```